# Parse: Kill process/user

Tags: android, parse-platform

I saw at Events Graph that my application has a lot of reqs in some days, like 60k/80k. My app has like 10/20 users.

So I analyze on Explorer and saw that just one application/installation made these reqs and in a specific Class. But this class it's old, doesn't exist anymore on my project. I think that it's an old installation/code and it's running on server, I don't know why.

How can I kill the process or ban the installation id? Something like this, there is anyway to do that?

Comment: You can delete the row corresponding to user of Installation class.

Comment: @Bluety deleting the row prevents of the user sent push, not request to server...